# How to use Javascript to review and change submit value of a form depending on content?

Tags: javascript, forms, input, indexof, onsubmit

I would like to change the value of an input field when the form is submitted depending on it's content.

Currently I have this and expect I am a long way from what I actually need, can't seem to find the info I am after to make it all work together.

Any help appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function vet()
{
    if(this.abc.value.indexOf("CW-") >= 0)
    {
    return true;
    }
    else
    {
    this.abc.value = 'CW-' + this.abc.value; return true;
    }
}
</script>

<form name="simple1" method="get" onsubmit="vet()" action="simple.php">
<input class="saip1" name="abc" type="text" value="Input Value" onfocus="this.value='';"/>
```

Basically I want to check that the user has included "CW-" (or indeed any case variant of that cw- cW- Cw-) at the beginning of their value. If they have just return the value as it is. If not I would like to add CW-.

After some reading I tried the indexOf approach but I don't really understand javascript and am sure I have done something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is fine but you were making it a little complicated.

Also, it's good practice to use `onsubmit` etc. through JavaScript instead of through HTML. You could also do this for `onfocus`.

http://jsfiddle.net/PTspF/

**HTML:**

```
<form id="simple1" method="get" action="simple.php">

    <input class="saip1" name="abc" type="text" value="Input Value" onfocus="this.value='';"/>

</form>
```

**JavaScript:**

You could check for an `indexOf` of `0` as you wish "CW-" to appear at the beginning of the string. The `toUpperCase()` makes `cw-` `CW-` so that variations also are found correct.

```
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("simple1").onsubmit=function() {
    if (this.abc.value.toUpperCase().indexOf("CW-") !== 0) {
      this.abc.value = 'CW-' + this.abc.value; // prepend if not present
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, is there anyway that I can call the form by it's name rather than it's order as this form is used on several pages and on some it is not the first form?

Comment: Since Dave obviously is new to JS, make sure it is understood that adding the handler has to be after load or after the tag

Comment: @Dave yes `document.simple1.onsubmit` or `document.forms["simple1"].onsubmit` or give it an id and use `document.getElementById("simple1").onsubmit` which is the most practical since some validators do not like a form name

Comment: I changed the function to be an anonymous function assigned on page load. It assumes `<form id="simple1"...` http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/Jdyfx/

Comment: Consider using jQuery. It will make things much easier - and if you search for plain JavaScript solutions chances are good that you find really crappy code people used to write long time ago (and some unformtunately still do.. setTimeout with a string arugment for example).

Comment: Do not consider jQuery until you have a grasp of basic javascript since it is invaluable to learn how it works before you pollute it with a framework

Comment: @Pim - try again. I copied the existing code but forgot to remove the onload in the left menu

Comment: @mplungjan: Thanks to you both for your help.